cygwin diff: missing the plus- and minus-characters in the output
in cygwin, the diff-command started each of its output-lines with some minus- or plus-characters. I build a script which relys on this leading minus- or plus-characters.
I had to install a newer release of cygwin and now this script does not work anymore, because the output of diff now starts with < or > .
How do I get the older/previous output back?

You could reference the diff man page or info pages to see the output format options. I think there is an option to use the old output format. Also, you might be able to pipe the diff output through a sed command like diff F1 F2 | sed -s'/^</-/' -s'/^>/+/'. Be sure that is executed by CYGWIN's bash.

It sounds like you are looking for the unified diff output format. You can request that with the -u option, e.g. diff -u file1 file2.
